# Migration from v12 to v16: TS errors in template

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, eslint, tslint

I would to migrate a big app from Angular 12 to Angular 16. The app is made through Ionic (also migrated from 5 to 7).

To do this, I performed a migration of:

- TSlint to ESlint
- Typescript 4.3 to 5.0

I resolved a lot of errors from linter (through IDE PhpStorm).

When I run the app in development, no problem the app works correctly, but when I try to build in production environment, a lot of errors are raised from templates.

An error like this:

```
Error: src/app/signup/signup.page.html:134:93 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

134             <ion-button class="next" routerLink="/login" [disabled]="isLoading" *ngIf="data.isAlreadyLinked">{{ 'signup.login' | transloco }}</ion-button>
                                                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In fact, the object `data` will not null because there is a check just above to display this component.

The problem is :

- there are a lot of errors raised by `ng run app:build:production`
- the IDE doesn't detect these errors
- I can't fix all errors raised from command line (very hard).

So, do you know a solution to:

- display the TS errors of templates in PhpStorm, or
- disable template TS errors check during production build, or
- any solution to unblock me?

Comment: Have you try to replace data.isAlreadyLinked with data?.isAlreadyLinked

Comment: This is the solution @A.Baudouin but I can't do this task for all errors without help of IDE for instance or another tool to identify easily each template errors for production environment.

Comment: Have use the guide from angular step by step here ? https://update.angular.io/?v=12.0-16.0

Comment: Yes @JFPicard. Errors are related to TS/ESlint upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Actually new verion of typescript, strict null check is enable by default. So you can disable by adding below line in **tsconfig.json** file.

```
"strictNullChecks": false
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: It works @Sourabh Chopade for TS2532 but I have another errors like TS7053, TS4111... Any idea to bypass these check only for templates ?

Comment: For TS4111 use "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false in tsconfig.json compilerOptions and for TS7053 could you please post the screenshot of exact error message with code snippet? @clem

Comment: In fact, I decided to resolve these TS errors in templates @Sourabh Chopade. So, now, the app can build correctly (except if I set strictNullChecks to true but the only solution is to resole all errors)